# reading the content of a request - ReadAsStringAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm attempting to read the content of the request like so:

`var translation = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

But getting this exception:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Content'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Here are the libraries I am using:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? **How can I read the body of the content?**

Here's the surrounding code:

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "OnTranslateSingleHttpTriggered")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var translation = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //do work
    }
```

Comment: Content is a property of HttpResponseMessage/HttpRequestMessage, not HttpRequest. You'd have to show the rest of your code to see how to get the right type of object.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/http-and-webhooks) says to use HttpRequestMessage to access the body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Garr mentioned, Content is a property of HttpRequestMessage. In v2 Functions which targets at .NET Core 2, we usually use HttpRequest and read content as below.

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

**Update**

Runtime 2.0.12265 has been available to VS users, feel free to use .NET Core 2.2.

---

Also note that .NET Core 2.2 is supported since [runtime v2.0.12265](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12265) but the runtime update has not been rolled out everywhere, i.e. we still consume the old one locally. So revert `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package to `2.1.0` or we may get error. (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` is referenced by `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` hence no need to install again)

Your project file(Right click on project, `Edit <FunctionProjectName>.csproj`) should look like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```